# How to set the runtime version for Dataproc Serverless

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

The various runtimes are listed here:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/concepts/versions/dataproc-serverless-versions

When submitting a batch job how do you set which runtime it executes under?

I tried looking in the documentation and searching the web, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `--version` flag in [`gcloud` CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/batches/submit/spark):

```bash
--version=VERSION
Optional runtime version. If not specified, a default version will be used.
```

If you are using API/Client Library then you can set it via `version` field in [`RuntimeConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.batches#RuntimeConfig).